# Unlock LXDE in terminal (for bluetooth unlocking Lubuntu)

Tags: bluetooth, terminal, command, screensaver, ubuntu

I use `blueproximity` to lock my pc.
In blueproximity you specify which commands to run for lock and unlock.
For locking Lubuntu I use `dm-tool lock` (lightdm)

For unlocking, `dm-tool switch-to-user $USER` does not work.
Found [someone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455926/unlock-screen-in-14-04-without-gnome-screensaver-command) suggesting `xdotool` (move mouse and then type the password) haven't tried this since it can be done better.

Any suggestions?
(less installing == greater happiness; i.e. gnome screensaver isn't desired)

Comment: I think you have to provide a session log in without providing a password. This link sais the default is to just show a 'greeter', which I assume is a login page. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/dm-tool.1.html

Note that things inside [] are optional. the default implementation is then to show the 'greeter'. Using xdotool is probably a bad idea, since you'd have to store your password in plaintext.